# Is CI for iOS Development possible on linux?

Tags: ios, linux, continuous-integration

I need to setup a Continuous Integration environment for iOS Development, and I have it setup already for my Java Project on a linux machine. So would it be possible to setup this up iOS as well on linux itself? (OR would we require a machine with OS only?)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Install app named "WINE" on linux so u can access VMWARE.exe that can run on your linux, you can run VMWARE based MacOs in VMWARE

Comment: This seems to equivalent to using a virtual machine with MAC OS, right?

Comment: yap you can download MacOs for VMware and Windows VmWare app run in linux with the help of Wine app So i think it's work for You